# Android View setting RippleDrawable progammatically yields smaller ripple

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I have the following TextView with a ripple:

```xml
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

If I click on it, it looks like this:

[image]

However, when removing the background:

```
-    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

and setting a ripple programmatically using:

```kotlin
val rippleDrawable = RippleDrawable(
  ColorStateList.valueOf(0x33FFFFFF.toInt()),
  null,
  ShapeDrawable(OvalShape())
)
binding.imageView.background = rippleDrawable
```

I get a smaller ripple:

[image]

Does anybody know why and how I can get the exact same size from the first ripple, when using `RippleDrawable`?

Comment: Pass null for the third argument in the constructor call. The ripple you're seeing from `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` is what they call "unbounded", which basically just means that it doesn't have a mask or other layer set.

Comment: @MikeM. amazing, that works. If you want please post it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Oh, I'm good. Nothin' huge. Please feel free to finish this up however you like. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad I could help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [Mike M.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76163423/android-view-setting-rippledrawable-progammatically-yields-smaller-ripple?noredirect=1#comment134316134_76163423) the solution is to use `null` instead of `ShapeDrawable(OvalShape())` to make the ripple unbounded:

```kotlin
val rippleDrawable = RippleDrawable(
  ColorStateList.valueOf(0x33FFFFFF.toInt()),
  null,
  null
)
```